# Estimating the size of the largest fully connected set in a random graph with $n$ vertices where each possible edge has probability $p$ of existing.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

Let $G := G(n, p)$ be a random graph with $n$ vertices where each possible edge has probability $p$ of existing. The existence of the edges are independent to each other. With $G$, we say $A \subset \{1,2,··· ,n\}$ is a fully connected set if and only if
$$i,j\in A \Rightarrow \text{i−th and j−th vertices are (directly) connected with an edge in }G$$
Define $T$ as the size of the largest fully connected set
$$T := \max\{|A| : A \text{ is a fully connected set}\}$$
Let’s fix $p ∈ (0, 1)$, prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\bigg[\frac{T}{2\log_{\frac{1}{p}}n}\le 1+\epsilon\bigg]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\bigg[\frac{T}{\sqrt{2\log_{\frac{1}{p}}n}}\ge 1-\epsilon\bigg]=1,~~\forall\epsilon>0$$

It is obvious that $\mathbb P[T=n]=p^{n(n-1)/2}$, and I think this proposition can be used to derive the estimate (in some manner), but I don't know how. May I ask how to derive the estimate of the size of the largest fully connected set? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, these estimates rely on the following method :

1. Consider sets $A$ of appropriate size : here $N = [(1 + \varepsilon) 2 \log_{1/p} n]$ for instance, if you are first interested in the upper bound.
2. Compute, for such a set, the probability that it is connected. In this case, you should find :

$$ \mathbb{P}(A \mbox{ is fully connected}) = p^{N(N-1)/2} $$

3. For the upper bound, you usually don't need to compute the correlation between the events $\{ A \mbox{ is fully connected} \}$ : you count that the number of sets of size $N$ is :

$$ \binom{n}{N} \sim \frac{n^N}{N!} $$

4. And then you can simply write by subadditivity :

$$ \mathbb{P}(T \geq N) = \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup \{ A \mbox{ is fully connected} \} \right) \\
\leq \binom{n}{N} e^{\frac{N(N-1)}{2} \ln(p)} \\
\sim e^{N (\frac{(N-1) \ln(p)}{ 2} + \ln(n))} \frac{1}{N!} $$

5. Finally, you just need the following asymptotics :

$$ \frac{(N-1) \ln(p)}{2} + \ln(n) \sim - \varepsilon \ln(n) $$

This conclude that $\mathbb{P}(T \geq N)$ goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. For the lower bound, you will usually use, instead of subadditivity, some property of independance by choosing sets $A$ of appropriate size $N = [\sqrt{2 \log_{1/p} n} (1 - \varepsilon)]$ that are disjoint one from another, and you can therefore take $\left[ \frac{n}{N}\right] $ such sets.

Now you replace step 4 by :

$$ P(T \leq N) \leq \left(1 - p^{N(N-1)/2}\right)^{[n/N]} = e^{[n/N] \ln(1 - p^{N(N-1)/2})} $$

And then :

$$ \left[ \frac{n}{N} \right] \ln(1 - p^{N(N-1)/2}) \sim - \frac{n}{N} p^{N(N-1)/2} = -e^{\frac{-N(N-1) \ln(p)}{2} + \ln(n) - \ln(N)}  $$

And finally :

$$ \frac{-N(N-1) \ln(p)}{2} + \ln(n) - \ln(N) \sim \varepsilon \ln(n) $$

so that $\left[ \frac{n}{N} \right] \ln(1 - p^{N(N-1)/2}) \to -\infty$ and thus $P(T \leq N) \to 0$.

I hope this helps. (Note that choosing the floor or ceil integer for $N$ has actually no consequence on the result.)